# Can some of the (timelike) curves which make up a (timelike) congruence be tangent to each other? (Or are they all strictly disjoint?)

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mathematical-physics, geometry

A [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)) is a useful notion in general relativity, relating mathematcal definition and physical interpretation:

> *"A congruence (more properly, a congruence of curves) is the set of integral curves of a (nowhere vanishing) vector field in a four-dimensional Lorentzian manifold [...]"*

Following up some intuition (mostly concerning timelike congruences) I find the following description [further down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(general_relativity)#Relation_with_vector_fields) on the Wikipedia page especially relevant:

> *"The integral curves of the vector field are a family of **non-intersecting** parameterized curves which fill up the spacetime. The congruence consists of the curves themselves, without reference to a particular parameterization."*

The emphasis on ***non-intersecting*** is placed in the Wikipedia article already; however without any further supporting explanation or link. To me, this raises an ambiguity:

- The phrase *"non-intersecting curves"* might be understood as referring to each of the (unparametrized) curves as a set (consisting of events), meaning that the [**intersection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of any two of these sets is [**empty**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#The_empty_set).
  In other words: **(pairwise) disjoint** sets.

Or:

- The phrase *"non-intersecting curves"* might be understood (in a geometric sense) as allowing the possibility of at least some instances of **being tangent to each other**; corresponding to the general geometric description of such mutually tangent curves as ["touching but **not intersecting**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22touching+but+not+intersecting%22);
  thus allowing at least some pairs of curves to have **at least one point (event) in common**, "in which they are tangent to each other".

Accordingly (and without hinting at my intuition) my question: **Which is it?**

Comment: A vector field $U^\mu$ on space time $M$ is a $\mathbb R^4$-valued function on $M\,.$
Its integral curves $t\mapsto y(t)$ are nothing else than solutions of a first order ODE $\dot y=U(y)\,.$ The [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) guarantees under mild conditions that two different integral curves cannot have points in common. Otherwise, the solution with initial condition $y(0)$ being such a common point would not be unique.

Comment: @Kurt G.: _"[...] guarantees under mild conditions [...]"_ -- Is the requirement of timelikeness (by itself) sufficient to meet these _"mild conditions"_ ? Or otherwise: Could you please sketch a counterexample, i.e. a timelike congruence with some (pairs of) tangent curves ? (If you expand either approach into an answer, I'd accept it.)

Comment: Thanks for the offer. When I have my physicist's hat on I do not look for counterexamples of that sort. The mild conditions Picard-Lindelöf needs are just Lipschitz continuity of $U\,.$ Counterexamples can be snatched from the mathematicians probably by the [dozens](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239284/can-a-differential-equation-have-non-unique-solutions).

Comment: @Kurt G. -- Well, I remain committed to reward an answer investigating any relation between light cones and Lipschitz cones. (Perhaps it involves "only some further _mild assumtions_" ? ...) Much more important to me is: Since I can't rely on the Wikipedia notion of "congruence" to convey my intuition, I'll instead refer to [E Poisson's notion of "congruence"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22A+congruence+in+O+is+a+family+of+curves+such+that+through+each+point+in+O+there+passes+one+and+only+one+curve+from+this+family%22) ...